# Although React doesn't allow objects as children, my code clearly says otherwise

Tags: reactjs

So I came across this bizarre behavior — when I try to setState using objects, it only fails in SOME cases.

For example this works,

```
getUserClaimAmount().then(
      userClaimAmount => {
        this.setState({ userClaimAmount: userClaimAmount.toString()})
      }
    );
```

But the following does not. It will throw an error saying that React children are not allowed to be objects.

```
getUserClaimAmount().then(
      userClaimAmount => {
        this.setState({ userClaimAmount: userClaimAmount})
      }
    );
```

However, the following works for some reason. "bettingPoolTotal" is the same type as "userClaimAmount" above.

```
getBettingPoolTotal().then(
      bettingPoolTotal => {
        this.setState({ total: bettingPoolTotal });
      }
    );
```

Below is a screenshot of what the state looks like. It's clear that there's obviously React children that are indeed objects.
[Example of React state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTKPa.png)

Comment: State is allowed to be objects, the real question is are you trying to render these objects directly

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the `children` property and the `state` of the component.

`children` property is populated by React when you create the component. Considering the following JSX:

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 />
    text here
    <Child2 />
</Parent>
```

The `children` property of `Parent` will be an array with three entries: the element created from `Child1`, string `"text here"` and the element created from `Child2`. If you try to pass the plain JavaScript object into the final markup (not into the React component, since it can use it as it want without error, but into native HTML tag), it won't work:

```
 <div>
     {{key: value}}
 </div>
```

That's exactly the error you're getting. It seems that there is some element which has `this.state.userClaimAmount` passed as children entity, and so errors when it gets a plain object instead of string or JSX.

As for the state - it's entirely possible to have plain objects inside it; however, this should be used very cautiously. Consider the following case inside some component which has an `obj` field in its state:

```
const obj = this.state.obj;
obj.key = 'value';
this.setState({obj: obj});
```

The last `setState` here surprisingly become a no-op, since the state is already changed by this moment - through the reference copied to `obj`, - and then React, knowing that this is a no-op, doesn't trigger rendering, leaving component the same as before.

Comment: I see. This answers my question and clears my confusion. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, if it's applicable, so that your question will be marked as solved :)